# Merge CSV rows based on duplicate key and combine unique values using Perl Text::CSV

Tags: perl, csv

I have a big tab-separated file with duplicate products but with different colours and amounts. I’m trying to merge the data based on the key so that I end up with one product and the combined colours and amounts separated by a delimiter (comma in this case).

I'm using the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) module so that I have better control, and because it allows me to output the file with a different delimiters (from semicolon to pipe).

My question is, how do I merge the data properly? I don't want it simply to combine colours and amounts but remove duplicate values as well. So I was thinking a key/value with the `Id`/`Amount` and `Id`/`Colour`. But `Id` isn't unique so how do I do this? Do I create an array or use hashes?

Here is some sample source data, with the tab separators replaced by semicolons `;`. Note that the marked row has no Colour so the empty value is not combined in the result.

```
Cat_id;Cat_name;Id;Name;Amount;Colour;Bla;    
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;500;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;1000;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;50;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;1;Purple;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;100;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;100;Purple;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;500;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;1000;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;500;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500;Green;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;500;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;500;White;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;2000;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;1000;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;100;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;1000;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;250;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100;White;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;500;Yellow;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;1000;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;1000;Green;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;200;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;200;White;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;50;Orange;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;2;White;1;
```

And the desired result I'm trying to get:

```
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100,500,200;Red,White;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;50,500,1000,10;Yellow,Green,Red;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500,1000;Red,Green;1;    
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;250,50,500,1000,100;Orange,Yellow,White,Purple;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;1000,500,2000;Green;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;100,1000,200,500;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;500,1000;Yellow,Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;2,1;White,Purple;1;
```

This is my script so far. It's not finished (and not working) because I'm not sure how to continue. I don't think this can work right because I'm trying to use the same key for different colours.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my $inputfile  = shift || die "Give input and output names!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output name!\n";

open my $infile,  '<', $inputfile   or die "Sourcefile in use / not found :$!\n";
open my $outfile, '>', $outputfile  or die "Outputfile in use :$!\n";

binmode($outfile, ":encoding(utf8)");

my $csv_in  = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1,sep_char => ";",eol => $/});
my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1,sep_char => "|",always_quote => 1,eol => $/}); #,quote_null => 0 #

my %data;

while (my $elements = $csv_in->getline($infile)){
    my $id = $elements->[2];
    push @{ $data{$id} }, \@elements;       
    }

for my $id ( sort keys %data ){
    my $set = $data{$id};
    my @elements = @{ $set->[0] };
    $elements[4] = join ',', uniq map { $_->[4] } @$set;
    $elements[5] = join ',', uniq map { $_->[5] } @$set;
    $csv_in->combine(@$elements);
    $csv_out->print($outfile, $elements);
    }
```

**Edit: I'm using data::dumper for testing but eventually want it written to a file.**

Comment: Your data uses a semicolon `;` separator, but your code and your narrative says that it uses a horizontal tab `"\t"`, which is it? Also, are there other fruits than `grape`, and other vegetables than `carrot`? And does *"column header just for clarification"* mean that the first line of the sample data isn't really there?

Comment: And `Grape;100,500,200;White,Red` seems a little odd as each colour has a total of 800 in three lots. Do you want the individual quantities listed for each colour, or do you really want the totals?

Comment: @Borodin You are right, the original data is tab separated. And yes, there are all sorts of fruits and vegetables but since they have the same ID it's irrelevant. No, the source has a header but i didn't think it mattered. I want to keep it in the outputfile though. No I looking to get the individual quantities.. Sorry if my sample data isn't making sense but it resembles the data I have.

Comment: ►By *"they have the same ID"* I assume you mean the same `Cat_id`? Surely you don't want melon, passion fruit etc. all on the same line in the output? ►Suppose you had 500, 200, and 100 white grapes and 300, 400, and 100 red grapes. How would the output line `101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100,500,200;White,Red;1;` change? ►The header line matters for a few reasons. Its contents need to be retained to create the correct header line on the output, and it is useful to use labels and variable names in the program that correspond to the names in the real data so as to make the code more readable.

Comment: Just an idea, are you perhaps looking for a list of all the *distinct* Amount values? So in my example above, the output should be `101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100,200,300,400,500;White,Red;1;`? But do melons and grapes have the same `Id`? All of this seems rather counter-intuitive. Is this a homework example?

Comment: @Borodin I ment column 2 as ID. 0 is the category id and doesn't matter. No I don't want them on the same outputline, i've modified my sample data so you can get a better idea of want i'm after. The line would then be    101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100,500,200,300,400;White,Red;1; Yes, I agree with the header. In short, yes..I'm looking for the unique values for both amounts and colours based on column 2. Melons and grapes do not have the same Id. No this is a special case on work i'm working on :( My script gives an error: Can't use string ("some value") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes deal with unique keys. As you've correctly surmised - if you 'overwrite' colour, then ... the old value is replaced.

But hashes *can* contain array(ref)s. So you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my $id = 50010;
my %hash;
$hash{$id}{'colour'} = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
push( @{ $hash{$id}{'colour'} }, "orange" );

print Dumper \%hash;
```

This'll work, provided you don't have any duplicates for the colours. (e.g. there's only one line for White Grapes with that ID.).

You may have to post-process with `join`, to turn the array into a string.

Or as an alternative, you could concatenate the colours onto the existing:

```
if ( defined $hash->{$id}->{colour} ) {
    $hash->{$id}->{colour} .= ",$colour";
}
```

I would also note - I'm unclear what you're doing with `$elements->[10]` because there aren't 10 columns. I would also strongly suggest *not* using generic names for variables - like `%hash` - because it's just a bad habit to get into. Vague variable names are bad style and whilst it's largely academic when you're looking at a small chunk of code, it pays to get into the habit of making it clear what you can expect to be in a particular variable. (Especially true if it's not clear of data types)

Comment: *"because it's just a bad habit to get into"* isn't a great reason!

Comment: That's true. Using unclear variable names is generally bad style though, even if it is irrelevant given a small code snippet. Which is sort of what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write a proper commentary, but this program seems to do what you need. It uses the `uniq` function from the [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) modules. It isn't a core module and so may need installing. I trust that it's not important what order the Amounts and Colours appear in the combined fields?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

print scalar <DATA>;

my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /;/;
  my $id = $fields[2];
  push @{ $data{$id} }, \@fields;
}

for my $id ( sort keys %data ) {
  my $set = $data{$id};
  my @fields = @{ $set->[0] };
  $fields[4] = join ',', uniq map { $_->[4] } @$set;
  $fields[5] = join ',', uniq map { $_->[5] } @$set;
  print join(';', @fields, ''), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Cat_id;Cat_name;Id;Name;Amount;Colour;Bla;    
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;500;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;1000;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;50;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;1;Purple;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;100;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;100;Purple;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;500;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;1000;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;500;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500;Green;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;500;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;500;White;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;2000;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;1000;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;100;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;1000;Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;250;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;100;White;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;500;Yellow;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;1000;Yellow;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;1000;Green;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;200;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;200;White;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;50;Orange;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;2;White;1;
```

**output**

```
Cat_id;Cat_name;Id;Name;Amount;Colour;Bla;    
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;500,100,200;Red,White;1;
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;500,1000,100,200;Red;1;
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;500,1000;Yellow,Green;1;
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500,1000;Green,Red;1;
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;100,500,250,1000,50;Purple,White,Yellow,Orange;1;
201;Vegetables;60050;Broccoli;500,1000,2000;Green;1;
201;Vegetables;60080;Onion;1,2;Purple,White;1;
201;Vegetables;60090;Tomato;50,100,500,1000;Green,Red,Yellow;1;
```

Comment: Thank you! No the order of amounts and colours is not important so this is good.. However, I prefer to work with the text::csv module since the file may contain quoted semicolons. So can I combine this with the text::csv module? then I'm going to try that